# Incomplete data save on HIVE for big table

Tags: matlab, hive, save

I am trying to save, "physically", a big table I have on Hive.

These are its properties:

- numFiles        1
- numRows 15849436012
- rawDataSize     445824806987
- totalSize       461674242999
- transient_lastDdlTime   1463600633

This the code I am using (before that I also increase the maximum size of a filesave):

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/directory/mytable'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
SELECT *
FROM mytable;

One Map command is generated, with 492 mappers. This reaches completion and aftr that it takes a lot of time to move the table to its destination folder. At some point (takes 4-5 hours approx.) the process terminates and a number of subfiles is saved, even though it is different every time.

The available disk space is now 3.5 TB.

When I try to scan it on Matlab I obtain an error stating that "columns/rows missing", "data does not seem to be tabular" towards the end of the process, which I interpret it signals the fact that the filesave is incomplete.

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post an example of the code you are using to do the insert and any configuration settings you may be setting manually. How far does it can in the map/reduce process and how many mappers or reducers are being created?

Comment: Just updated, thank you.